# How much money an e-commerce is making

Tags: e-commerce

I am very curious to find out how much money an e-commerce company is making.

Is there a way or ways to find this out (apart from techcrunch.com/) ?

Thanks

Comment: check out their tax returns :)

Answer (score 1):

It is going to depend on if the company is public or private.  Obviously with public companies, their earnings/profits are published each quarter.  There are also many other metrics which show how well a public company is doing (ie. stocks, dividends).  This information is available from a number of places.  Private companies are a bit different, as they really don't need to tell you much.  One can usually infer how well they are doing to a certain degree, however this has no guarantee of being accurate.

**Disclaimer**: I'm a developer, not an econ or business major :)

Comment: I have many e-commerce Ideas but before I put any time/effort into developing the application I want to make sure they are commercially viable. There are smaller and similar e-commerce available on internet so I thought the best way would be to look at how much money they are making from their idea/business.
I thought may be there is a simple strategy that could be used to find out their profit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a stackoverflow question but if they are publicly traded they have to submit forms to the sec and provide them to you upon request so you can go that route.  If not then you might just be out of luck.